# Using a secured mediaURL with twilio programable fax

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

I am using Twilio programmable fax API to send a fax from within my application. This is working fine if the mediaUrl doesn't require authentication. However, when using a URL that is secured with basic authentication, the fax is always failing.

I have accessed the secured URL from both within my company's domain, and from the outside, and this is working fine. I can also access using a HTTP request. But when using Twilio API, its failing.

On Twilio's website, they state to provide a username and password in the mediaUrl for basic authentication in the following format:

https://username:password@www.myserver.com/my_secure_document

The Twilio API looks like this:

```
  var sStatus = FaxResource.Create(
                                    from: sender,
                                    to: recipient,
                                    mediaUrl: uriAddress,
                                    storeMedia: false 
                                );
```

The api call itself doesn't generate any errors, however when retrieving the fax status, it shows as failed.

Password encoding has also been ruled out. There are a $ and # being used the the password encoded as %24 and %23.

There has already been a question on this topic with an accepted answer because Twilio updated their API. Using Twilio API version from the date it was marked as resolved and the latest version both result in failed faxes when using a mediaUrl with basic authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curious if your password has any characters that may need to be URL encoded, have you ruled out the special characters in the password being an issue?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Yes, this has been ruled out. There are a $ and # in the password being encoded as %24 and %23.

Comment: After further investigating the special characters and getting in contact with twilio support, turns out there is a bug with special characters in the mediaUrl. Removed special characters and it worked fine. Thanks for leading to this discovery